# linq to sql relationship

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I want to return a dataset with some relations, the query is OK but I get the ID instead of the real value from the other table... This is the query

```
        var thr=
            from u in dc.thresholds
            select u;
```

This returns something like this:

```
id: 1
name: some name
type_id: 1
owner_id: 1
```

I want to get type_id and owner_id with the values of theese tables, so it can be something like:

```
id: 1
name: some name
type_id: Danger
owner_id: John Smith
```

I hope some of you could give me some advices, I'm starting with LINQ to SQL and I'm a bit lost...

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `threshold` table and `type` table, also between `threshold` and `owner` table in the database ? , if so you will have an object of both the tables with your `threshold` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want show name value for type_id(type_name in other table) you should use join like this:

```
var thr=
            from u in dc.thresholds
        join y in dc.yourTable on u.type_id equal y.type_id
        select new{u.id,u.name,typeName=y.name,....};
```

Comment: I have one problem, when column "type_id" is empty, the query doesn't returns that row, because there is not join with Types.id.. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1381537 i dont know for solve this issu,in simple way you can create a empty row in another table.

Answer (score 0):

Use navigation properties to load data as needed.  If the navigation properties don't exist (Threshold.Type and Threshold.Owner), open your dbml and add associations.

Using navigation properties lazily will result in extra queries.

```
List<Threshold> result = dc.Thresholds.ToList();  //run first query

foreach(Threshold t in result)
{
  Type type = t.Type;  //run second query (per row)
  Owner owner = t.Owner; //run third query (per row)
}
```

---

Use DataLoadOptions to eagerly load related data during the query.

```
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Threshold>(t => t.Type);
options.LoadWith<Threshold>(t => t.Owner);

dc.LoadOptions = options;

List<Threshold> result = dc.Thresholds.ToList();  // run query

foreach(Threshold t in result)
{
  Type type = t.Type;  //these values are already loaded by this point.
  Owner owner = t.Owner;
}
```

---

Write query to load the data with the shape you want

```
var query =
  from t in dc.Thresholds
  let type = t.Type
  let owner = t.Owner
  select new {Threshold = t, Type = type, Owner = owner};

var result = query.ToList();  //run query

foreach(var x in result)
{
  Threshold t = x.Threshold;
  Type type = x.Type;  //might be null.
  Owner owner = x.Owner;  //might be null.
}
```